# can other-buffer in split windows select a visible buffer?

Tags: buffers, window, window-splitting

I often swap 2 most latest buffers back and forth with `(switch-to-buffer (other-buffer))`. This works just fine in most situations.

However, when I have 2 split windows, and the other window is opening a file I would switch to using the above command, `other-buffer` skips that buffer and it returns the 3rd-latest buffer instead. This is quite annoying.

Is there any way to swap 2 most latest buffers regardless of what other windows are opening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`other-buffer` takes an optional third argument that says it's
okay to use buffers visible in other windows.  The relevant bit of
the docstring:

> `(other-buffer &optional BUFFER VISIBLE-OK FRAME)`
>
> Return most recently selected buffer other than BUFFER.
>   **Buffers not visible in windows are preferred to visible buffers, unless
>   optional second argument VISIBLE-OK is non-nil.**  Ignore the argument
>   BUFFER unless it denotes a live buffer.  If the optional third argument
>   FRAME specifies a live frame, then use that frame’s buffer list instead
>   of the selected frame’s buffer list.

So: the following code should do what you want:

```
(switch-to-buffer (other-buffer (current-buffer) t))
```

That's a lot to type, however, so you may as well wrap it in a
command that you can bind to your key of choice:

```
(defun switcheroo ()
  "Switch to the most recent other buffer, even if it's visible
in another window."
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer (current-buffer) t)))
```

Comment: I'd suggest using nil as first argument.

Comment: @YoungFrog: I tested it lightly with `nil` as the second argument, and it didn't seem to behave as what I think OP wanted.  It was only a light test, though, so I could be wrong about that.

Comment: You're absolutely right, `(other-buffer nil t)` seems to return the currently selected buffer! Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @YoungFrog: no worries!